# Resize HOG feature for Scikit-Learn classifier

Tags: python, image, image-processing, scikit-learn, opencv3.0

I'm trying to execute this code that processes 70 images and extracts Histogram of Oriented Gradients (HOG) features. These are passed to a classifier (Scikit-Learn).

However, an error is raised:

```
hog_image = hog_image_rescaled.resize((200, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

I do not understand why, because with attempting with a single image works correctly.

```
#Hog Feature

from skimage.feature import hog
from skimage import data, color, exposure
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import os
import glob
import numpy as np
from numpy import array

listagrigie = []

path = 'img/'
for infile in glob.glob( os.path.join(path, '*.jpg') ):
    print("current file is: " + infile )
    colorato = Image.open(infile)
    greyscale = colorato.convert('1')

    #hog feature
    fd, hog_image = hog(greyscale, orientations=8, pixels_per_cell=(16, 16),
                    cells_per_block=(1, 1), visualise=True)

    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))
    print(type(fd))
    plt.subplot(121).set_axis_off()
    plt.imshow(grigiscala, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
    plt.title('Input image')

    # Rescale histogram for better display
    hog_image_rescaled = exposure.rescale_intensity(hog_image, in_range=(0, 0.02))
    print("hog 1 immagine shape")
    print(hog_image_rescaled.shape)

    hog_image = hog_image_rescaled.resize((200, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)    
    listagrigie.append(hog_image)
    target.append(i)

print("ARRAY of gray matrices")

print(len(listagrigie))
grigiume = np.dstack(listagrigie)
print(grigiume.shape)
grigiume = np.rollaxis(grigiume, -1)
print(grigiume.shape)

from sklearn import svm, metrics

n_samples = len(listagrigie)
data = grigiume.reshape((n_samples, -1))
# Create a classifier: a support vector classifier
classifier = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001)

# We learn the digits on the first half of the digits
classifier.fit(data[:n_samples / 2], target[:n_samples / 2])

# Now predict the value of the digit on the second half:
expected = target[n_samples / 2:]
predicted = classifier.predict(data[n_samples / 2:])
print("expected")

print("predicted")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should rescale the source image (named `colorato` in your example) to `(200, 200)`, then extract the HOG features and then pass the list of `fd` vectors to your machine learning models. The `hog_image` are just meant to visualize the feature descriptors in a user friendly manner. The actual features are returned in the `fd` variable.

Comment: it's possible that fd list is made of: [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.] ? the measure results, obviously are a sequence of 0

Comment: I am not sure, do you have uniformly colored areas in your picture?

Have you tried to check the values of `numpy.max(fd)` and `numpy.mean(fd)`?

Comment: ok it give me this: max: 0.999636109832 and media 0.104345580011, so i think i have to change something 'cause measure results of precision, recall, f1-score and support are all 0 and also avg / total when i print this: print "Classification report for classifier %s:\n%s\n" % (
    classifier, metrics.classification_report(expected, predicted))

Comment: Have you tried to find the optimal value for `C` and `gamma`? Have you tried a simpler model such as `LinearSVC`?

Comment: i tried to change gamma value, kernel (linear and rbf) but results are the same.i tried to run this code (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html) and show me 4 images with a red background and only 1 dot. I know, only, that something goes wrong. I think svm is not good for hog feature (i have a feature vector with 40.000 lenght) i tried K-means and when i print this. print k_means.labels_[::10] i have this result: [2 2 2 0 0 0 0 2]. I do not what it means.

Comment: I think it's all wrong, i need an algorithm that when i give an image sample recognize among 150 images and more the most similar images inside that group and i thought hog+svm was correct.

Comment: If you just want the closest image in HOG feature space you can compute the pairwise euclidean distances, and take the smallest. You don't need machine learning for this.

Also k-means is not a supervised classification algorithm but an unsupervised clustering algorithm: it find groups of similar stuff without labels.

Comment: yes, but i thought because my image are not cats, dogs, people but generical signs, it could be usuful an unsupervised classification that find groups of sign.

Comment: then professor talk me about looking for a feature extractor for these signs and to use a training set for training and a new image set for verifying the machine. So first of all i thing about contour feature like canny, sobel, and last hog to create feature vector for every image and a svm for training, but i'm new in this field and i have no idea what expect me as results by a svm, i thought that in scikit tutorials i have could found how use an svm and a metric which print me percentage of most similar images and modifying parameters of svm to improve results!

Comment: so are u sure i need only pairwise euclidean distances, and choose the smallest for my purpose? i thought if it is robustness in comparison two image with different scale, if recognize an image who was rotated, if the stroke is thin or not.. and something like that

Comment: ah sorry, yes i have uniformed colored areas in my pictures! white area! So it's right to have so many zeros?