# Obtaining a HOG feature vector for implementation in SVM in Python

Tags: image, python-2.7, scikit-learn, scikit-image

I am new to sci-kit learn. I have viewed the online tutorials but they all seem to leverage existing data (e.g., digits, iris, etc). I need the information on how to process images so that they can be used by scikit learn.

Details of my Study: I have a webcam set up outside my office. It captures all of the traffic on my street that passes in the field of view. I have cropped several hundred images of sedans, trucks and SUV's. The goal is to predict whether a vehicle is one of these categories. I have applied Histogram Oriented Gradients (HOG) to these images which I have attached for your review to see the differences in the categories. This blog will not allow me to post any images but you can see them here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/149421/obtaining-a-hog-feature-vector-for-implementation-in-svm-in-python. I posted the same question at this site but no response. This post is the closest answer I have found. [Resize HOG feature for Scikit-Learn classifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14173128/resize-hog-feature-to-put-in-classifier-scikit-learn)

I wish to train an SVM classifier based on these images. I understand that there are algorithms that exist in scikit-image that prepares the HOG images for use in scikit-learn. Can someone help me understand this process. I am also grateful for any thoughts based on your experience as to the probability of success of this classification study. I also understand that I need to train the model using a negative images ( ones with no vehicles. How is this done?

I know I am asking a lot but I am surprised no one that I am aware of has done a tutorial on these early steps. It seems like a fairly elementary study.